# VS c++ - error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker

The error shown is:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol  "void __cdecl gerarPadroesTeste(double * const,double,int (* const)[31])" (?gerarPadroesTeste@@YAXQANNQAY0BP@H@Z)
```

My current header file:

```
#define K 16
#define NR_PONTOS 9
#define NR_REP_TOTAL 100000

#define theta 0.50
#define tau 16
#define beta 6


int unif();
int somaMod2(int a, int b);
double gaussiana(double m, double sd);
double calcularPi(double zi, double variancia, bool computeBeta);

void gerarResultados(double snrdb, double ber, double wer, int nerrb, int nerrw, char* s);

void read_p();
void generate_gf();
void gen_poly();

void encode_bch(int u[], int rd[]);
void unirPalavraCodigo(int u[], int rd[], int c[]);
void decode_bch(int y[]);
void canalAWGN(double x[], double r[], double sd);
void chase(double r[N], int y[N], double variancia, int z[K]);
void gerarPadroesTeste(double r[N], double variancia, int pTeste[][N]);
double distanciaEuclidiana(double r[], int y[]);

void modularBPSK(int c[], double x[], double e);
void demodularBPSK(double r[], int y[]);

int pesoHamming(int a[]);
bool isValid(int yt[]);

double modulo(double n);
```

And my .cpp file has the implementation of all methods. I'll copy here the method that calls the failing method and the method itself:

```
void gerarPadroesTeste(int r[N], double variancia, int pTeste[][N])
{
    double p[N];
    double aux;

    for (int a = 0; a < N; a++){
        double mr = -modulo(r[a]);
        aux = calcularPi(mr, variancia, false);
        if (aux <= 0.5 - theta)
            p[a] = 0;
        else if (aux >= 0.5 + theta)
            p[a] = 1;
        else
            p[a] = calcularPi(mr, variancia, true);
    }

    for (int b = 0; b < tau; b++){
        for (int c = 0; c < N; c++){
            double k = rand();
            if (k/RAND_MAX <= p[c])
                pTeste[b][c] = 0;
            else
                pTeste[b][c] = 1;
        }
    }
}

void chase(double r[N], int y[N], double variancia, int z[K])
{
    int pTeste[tau][N];
    gerarPadroesTeste(r, variancia, pTeste);

    int i,j,m;
    int yt[N];
    int lambda[tau][N];

    for (i = 0; i < tau; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++){
            lambda[i][j] = -1;
        }
    }

    bool valido;
    for (i = 0; i < tau; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++){
            yt[j] = somaMod2(y[j],pTeste[i][j]);
        }

        decode_bch(yt);

        valido = isValid(yt);

        if (valido) {
            for (j = 0; j < N; j++){
                lambda[i][j] = yt[j];
            }
        }   
    }

    double minimo = 10000;

    for (i = 0; i < tau; i++){
        if (lambda[i][0] == -1)
            continue;
        else{
            for (j = 0; j < N; j++){
                yt[j] = lambda[i][j];
            }

            if (distanciaEuclidiana(r,yt) < minimo){
                minimo = distanciaEuclidiana(r,yt);
                for (m = 0; m < K; m++){
                    z[m] = yt[m+length-K];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your header you declared

```
void gerarPadroesTeste(double r[N], double variancia, int pTeste[][N]);
```

but in your cpp you defined

```
void gerarPadroesTeste(int r[N], double variancia, int pTeste[][N])
```

So the definition of the version with the first parameter double[N] is still missing.